# Determine Geometry of Multiple Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge, combine

I am sure this is a newbie question.

I am importing a large number of layers into QGIS from a complex .kml file and need to combine into a single layer and finally save as a .shp file.

I repeated run into the incompatible geometry error when I attempt to combine layers in Qgis.  I can check each layer to determine its geometry and change this, but given I am dealing with 100 or so layers, I am looking for a more efficient method (perhaps python query?) to identify all the layers'
geometries or other more automated method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'incompatible geometry error? What is the error message exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to combine different geometry types into one shapefile. This is afaik not possible. Every geometry type has to be written into its own shapefile. Changing geometry types means strongly changing the kind of data you are trying to process and shouldn't be done on a whim. I can recommand as a start the Qgis-plugin called 'Layer Arranger' which sorts your layers in groups by their geometry type.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nightwatch...This gets me started; however, the newly created category of "Group Line" contains multiple LineString types including LineString, LinestringZ, and MultiLineStringZ.  I am importing a complex kml file with hundreds of layers representing line segments that I would like to combine into a single shp file and the differing geometries prevent this.